# In push notification when user clear the app from the task manager the notification is not coming?

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I am using push notification in my app. it is working fine when the app is running or in the foreground state.but when the user clean the app from the task manager/tab then the notification is not coming. I tried many method like package restart and all. but i could not get the solution. if anyone know what i am doing wrong. please tell me.

This is my GcmBroadcastReceiver class :-

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

This is GcmIntentService class by which i send the notification :-

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private final static String TAG = "GcmIntentService";
    private Context mContext;


    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Data Json :" + extras.getString("message"));

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());

            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());

            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.d(TAG, " Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                            + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                sendNotification(extras.getString("message"));
            }
        }        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }     // Put the message into a notification and post it.


    private void sendNotification(String msg) {

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("KEY","aman");


        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Telepoh")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);


        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private int getNotificationIcon() {
        boolean useWhiteIcon = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
        return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.gcm : R.drawable.push_icon;
    }
}
```

And This is my Manifest :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="package_name"
        android:versionCode="2"
        android:versionName="1.2">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

        <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

        <permission
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

        <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

        <application

            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:replace="android:icon">

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="API_KEY" />

            <activity
                android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".LoginActivity"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
            <activity
                android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
            <activity android:name=".ForgetPasswordActivity" />


            <activity android:name="pacahe_name.controller.GalleryUtil" />

            <activity android:name="nl.changer.polypicker.ImagePickerActivity" />

            <receiver
                android:name="package_name.GCM.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <intent-filter>

                    <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                    <category android:name=package_name" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>


            <service android:name="package_name.GCM.GcmIntentService" />


            <activity
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/fb_id" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

The push notification working fine when the app in the run state and in the foreground state. But My problem is when app clean from the task manager then the notification is not coming.I tried package restarted but it does not working.If anyone know what i am doing wrong then please tell me.

Comment: What device running what version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: @DavidWasser I tried in different device.by the way now i am using marshmellow.